# How to return a cell by searching for a date with specific criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to find and return a cell from column E by searching for a cell in column A with the most recent date that has passed including today.

For example from the picture below, I'm looking for a formula that would return E18($16,550) if the date is March 25th, 2024. Once the date becomes April 5th, 2024, the formula should start returning E19($17250).

[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several options. Here's one using `MAXIFS`:

```
=INDEX(E:E,XMATCH(MAXIFS(A:A,A:A,"<="&TODAY()),A:A))
```

To verify this will return the expected results for future dates, consider:
[image]